# [ROS2] asyncio await with timeout a service call in a callback

Tags: ros, python, ros2, callbacks, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am trying to use the asyncio syntax to await for a service to complete inside a callback function of a Node. A dummy node to test this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.callback_groups import ReentrantCallbackGroup
from rclpy.executors import SingleThreadedExecutor
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from rcl_interfaces.srv import ListParameters
import asyncio

class TestNode(Node):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        Node.__init__(
            self,
            "test_node",
        )
        self.callback_group = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        self._sub = self.create_subscription(
            topic="test",
            msg_type=Empty,
            callback=self.cb_test,
            qos_profile=5,
            callback_group=self.callback_group,
        )

        self.client = self.create_client(
            ListParameters,
            "/test_node/list_parameters"
        )

    async def cb_test(self, msg: Empty) -> None:

        service_request = ListParameters.Request()
        srv_future = self.client.call_async(service_request)
        try:
            # result = await asyncio.wait_for(srv_future, timeout=10.0)
            result = await srv_future
        except Exception as e:
            self.get_logger().error(f"Service call failed! what(): {str(e)}")
        else:
            self.get_logger().info(f"Service call success! what(): {str(result)}")


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = TestNode()
    executor = SingleThreadedExecutor()

    rclpy.spin(node, executor)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.try_shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can test it with

```
ros2 topic pub -1 /test std_msgs/msg/Empty {}
```

That code works just fine. The callback function doesn't block any other callback functions and it returns the result of the service. Now If I want to add a timeout to that future with `asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=10.0)` it fails with:

```
[ERROR][1679007966.209838027][test_node]: Service call failed! what(): no running event loop
```

I tried everything, spawning a new event_loop in a separate thread, calling `event_loop.run_forever` in the main thread, and spawning the `rclpy.spin` in a thread. Nothing works.

I tried this alternative approach:

```
    # ... another method from the previous code
    def run(self):

        self.event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        # this task will run forever to process ROS node events
        async def rosloop():
            while rclpy.ok():
                rclpy.spin_once(self, timeout_sec=0)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)

        # perform main event loop processing
        try:
            asyncio.ensure_future(rosloop())
            self.event_loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            self.event_loop.close()
            self.event_loop = None

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = TestNode()    
    node.run()
    rclpy.try_shutdown()
```

Now I get the error:

```
[ERROR][1679008951.750327026][test_node]: Service call failed! what(): await wasn't used with future
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? Any asyncio and rclpy expert for advice? I want to stick with a Singlethreaded executor

[UPDATE] PD: If I use the [async_timeout](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout) package and the alternative approach for spinning the node it works, but I still don't want to depend on an external package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413482/%5Bros2%5D-asyncio-await-with-timeout-a-service-call-in-a-callback/) by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2023-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find a workaround using `asyncio.ensure_future` as follows:

```
class TestNode(Node):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        Node.__init__(
            self,
            "test_node",
        )
        self.callback_group = ReentrantCallbackGroup()

        self._sub = self.create_subscription(
            topic="test",
            msg_type=Empty,
            callback=self.cb_test,
            qos_profile=5,
            callback_group=self.callback_group,
        )

        self.client = self.create_client(
            ListParameters,
            "/test_node/list_parameters",
            callback_group=MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup(),
        )

    def cb_test(self, msg: Empty) -> None:
        # Schedule the async function and add it to the node's callback group.
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.async_cb_test(msg))

    async def async_cb_test(self, msg: Empty) -> None:
        service_request = ListParameters.Request()
        srv_future = self.client.call_async(service_request)
        try:
            result = await asyncio.wait_for(srv_future, timeout=10.0)
        except Exception as e:
            self.get_logger().error(f"Service call failed! what(): {str(e)}")
        else:
            self.get_logger().info(f"Service call success! what(): {str(result)}")


async def spin(executor: SingleThreadedExecutor):
    while rclpy.ok():
        executor.spin_once()
        # Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run.
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = TestNode()
    executor = SingleThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(node)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(spin(executor))

    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

---

Originally posted by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) with karma: 87 on 2023-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0